# Distinguish the final property from the intermediate properties being accessed with javascript proxies

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, es6-proxy

Is there a way to figure out if the property being read of a proxy object is the final property or the intermediate property.

```
var handler = {
  get(target, key) {
      return new Proxy(target[key], handler) 
  },
  set (target, key, value) {
    target[key] = value;
    return true
  }
}
var proxyObject = new Proxy({}, handler);
```

Now if I am reading a property `proxyObject.a.b.c.d`, the get handler would be invoked 4 times, once for each property.
Is there a way for me to figure out when the get is fired for the `d` property and when the get is fired for some intermediate property like `a` or `b`

Comment: @AyushGoel there are plenty of hacks that make assumptions about how the code is organized and whether or not intermediate references can be stored and accessed later, or if all accesses happen synchronously, etc. but of course these assumptions don't cover all use cases. In general, no this is not possible.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts could you point me to one such hack? It would give me some idea on where to start

Comment: Is `d`'s value an object? If not - that is, if it's a primitive - then one *flimsy* method would be to return a Proxy *if* the `target[key]` is an object, and otherwise just return `target[key]`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm doing that anyway, cause recursive proxies for primitive objects won't make much sense. I didn't put that in the snippet above to make it simpler. 
Doing that still won't help me distinguish if a property is intermediate or the final one.

Comment: I answered a question like this before... still trying to find a link to it.

Comment: I can't think of any halfway decent solution either, at least not one that preserves the ability to access what's *actually* behind `.d` while accessing via `proxyObject.a.b.c.d`. You might consider `const dVal = proxyObject.a.b.c.d; console.log(dVal.e)` - what happens then? Pretty sure there's no way to generically identify `d` as the last property before it gets put into `dVal`. You could think about accessing not through proxies, but through a completely separate method, such as `getValue(someObject, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])`. Similar outcome, different accessor syntax.